# Android, get wrong Date convert from GregorianCalendar.getTime()

Tags: android

```
GregorianCalendar gd1 = new GregorianCalendar(2013,12,12);

Date d = gd1.getTime();

Sun Jan 12 00:00:00 EST 2014  <===== what's wrong?
```

Is there a simpler way to construct Date for certain date (the Date(year, month, day) is deprecated).
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GregorianCalendar class' months are zero-based (many people see this as a mistake, but that's not the point).

If you actually want to put the date as December 12, 2013, you would have to use the following line:

```
GregorianCalendar gd1 = new GregorianCalendar(2013,11,12);
```

Comment: Thanks Adam! Using (2013,11,12) does give the Thu Dec 12 00:00:00 EST 2013

But the spec http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar(int, int, int) is misleading?

public GregorianCalendar (int year, int month, int day)

Added in API level 1
Constructs a new GregorianCalendar initialized to midnight in the default TimeZone and Locale on the specified date.

Parameters
year the year.
month the month.
day the day of the month.

Comment: You are right. It is misleading, but your link doesn't mention that "parameter month the month" is actually from 1 to 12, though it is logical that most (if not all) people see it that way. If you go to the "inherited constants" section in the link in your comment, you will see that the constants are inherited from Calendar and, for instance, APRIL = 3.

I can't explain why it is that way, but I agree that it is counter-intuitive, especially since days are 1-based while months are 0-based, which is just really inconsistent and a mess in general.